# Boxing/Unboxing and Nullable?

Tags: .net, nullable

I understand that boxing and unboxing is about casting (real type to object... object to real type). But I do not understand what the MSDN say about it with the Nullable. Here is the text I do not understand:

> When a nullable type is boxed, the common language runtime automatically boxes the underlying value of the Nullable object, not the Nullable object itself. That is, if the HasValue property is true, the contents of the Value property is boxed. When the underlying value of a nullable type is unboxed, the common language runtime creates a new Nullable structure initialized to the underlying value. [Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

When you change your object to a real type, the real type variable that was nullable will be the type of object? I do not get it?

Comment: Great minds think alike.  (cf @Jon and @Marc)

Comment: Great minds need to take a holiday from SO :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What it's saying is that if you do:

```
int? x = 5;
object y = x; // Boxing
```

You end up with a boxed `int`, not a boxed `Nullable<int>`. Similarly if you do:

```
int? x = null; // Same as new Nullable<int>() - HasValue = false;
object y = x; // Boxing
```

Then y ends up as a null reference.

Comment: @Jon in the second case, there is no boxing, the documentation is clear about it. It just assigns a null reference. Only when `HasValue` flag is true (non null value), the underlying value type is boxed. Spot on about *You end up with a boxed `int`, not a boxed `Nullable<int>`*, I had the misconception myself.

Comment: @nawfal: It assigns a null reference, but that's a boxing operation which yields a null reference. Look in the generated IL (I just double checked) - it's using the `box` instruction. There's a difference between "a boxing operation" and "an operation which returns a boxed value" IMO. Which documentation were you referring to?

Comment: @JonSkeet http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597.aspx I quote: *Objects based on nullable types are only boxed if the object is non-null. If HasValue is false, the object reference is assigned to null instead of boxing.*

Comment: @nawfal: I counter with C# spec section 4.3.1: "Boxing a value of a nullable-type produces a null reference if it is the null value." I think it makes sense to consider it still a boxing operation - just one that doesn't create a box. Just like a casting operation is still a casting operation even if it fails at execution time.

Comment: @JonSkeet thats some info. Thanks, will try remembering it hard! :) Can you see to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20655473/boxed-nullable-underlying-type-can-be-cast-to-enum-but-boxed-enum-type-cant-be. Felt it will be interesting.. :)

Answer (score 8):

What that means is that if you do:

```
int? i = 5;
object o = i;
```

it is an "int" (5) that is boxed, not an "int?" (5). If x had been null (!HasValue), o would be null, not a box around an empty "int?"

Then when you unbox:

```
i = (int?)o;
```

If o is null, i becomes an empty "int?"; otherwise, the 5 is unboxed and used to create an "new int?(5)".

Basically, you shouldn't (short of cheating) be able to get a boxed `nullable<T>` directly - only a boxed `T`

Comment: " If x had been null " should be " If i had been null "... x variable is on JonSkeet example... you used i.

Comment: Mind you, Jon posted his answer half-finished so he'd get oldest answer. So they're even.

Comment: lol!! I promise, it was all independent - even the x was pure coincidence. No, seriously!

Comment: @mackenir: Actually posting it half-finished was the result of trying to tab when coding. I hit tab-return, which posted the answer. I was most annoyed :(

Answer (score 3):

If a `Nullable<T>` is `null`, it'll be boxed as a null reference and will not behave as a boxed value type with `HasValue = true`.

In fact, to implement this feature, it was required that CLR intrinsically support `Nullable<T>` type and treat it differently. Developers can not write their own type that works like `Nullable<T>`.

It's worth noting that this was one of the late .NET 2.0 features. In early betas, `Nullable<T>` behaved just like a normal structure. In final release, it was changed to box to null reference. This change was specifically breaking for SQL Server CLR team and they had to change some fundamental stuff for it.