# is an object of value type also the nullable value type?

Tags: c#, ivalueconverter

I saw some code like this

```
if(value == null || !(value is double || value is double?))
{
    return value;
}
```

if value is double is true, value is double? should also be true, therefore can i change the code to

```
if(value == null || !(value is double?))
{
    return value;
}
```

Comment: `double?` is just syntactical sugar for `Nullable<double>`, therefore `double != Nullable<double>` (that I'm aware).

Comment: what exactly are you asking? this is somewhat unclear...

Comment: What is the method signature? Is it supposed to return a `double?` or a `double`?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `value` is an `object`, you can change the code to:

```
if (value == null || !(value is double))
{
   return value;
}
```

If `value` is a boxed `double?`, it will always either be `null` or a boxed `double`.

Comment: If you take a `double?` and box it (ie: store it in an `object`), then one of two things will happen. Either 1) the `double?` is `null`, in which case the `object` will be `null`; or 2) the `double?` is not `null`, in which case the `object` will contain a boxed `double`, and `obj is double` will be `true`.

Comment: See also "Boxing and unboxing" in the remarks of http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx#remarksToggle and the answers to this SO question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/374790/boxing-unboxing-and-nullable

Comment: _See Also [Boxing Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228597%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)_

Answer (score 0):

`Nullable<double>` is not the same type as `double`, its nullDouble.Value property however is a double.  The code you have included seems to show that it handles either or

Answer (score 0):

Keeping in mind that `double?` is really `Nullable<double>`, you *can* use `GetType` to see the original value type on a nullable data type. So, keeping the same test in mind:

```
if (value == null || value.GetType() != typeof(double))
{
    return value;
}
```

Since:

```
double           A = 1;  // A.GetType() = System.Double
double?          B = 1;  // B.GetType() = System.Double
Nullable<double> C = 1;  // C.GetType() = System.Double
```

*All assuming the first condition (`value == null`) short-circuits the test, this has the same outcome.*

Comment: _Just written differently than @Richard's answer._