# Boxed nullable underlying type can be cast to enum but boxed enum type can't be cast to nullable type

Tags: c#, casting, enums, nullable, boxing

- Boxed nullable underlying type **can be cast** to enum but boxed enum type **can't be cast** to nullable type.

And similarly,

- Boxed nullable enum **can be cast** to underlying type but boxed underlying type **can't be cast** to nullable enum.

*Ok, I know "boxed nullable type" is not the best way to describe it, but it's for the sake of the question. I'm aware it's the underlying value type that's getting boxed.*

I will show it with examples. Assume I have an `enum` with `int` as the underlying type.

```
enum Sex { Male, Female }
```

Case I:

```
int? i = 1;
object o = i;
Sex e = (Sex)o; //success

//but

Sex e = Sex.Male;
object o = e;
int? i = (int?)o; //invalid cast
```

Case II:

```
Sex? e = Sex.Male;
object o = e;
int i = (int)o; //success

//but

int i = 1;
object o = i;
Sex? e = (Sex?)o; //invalid cast
```

**In a nutshell,**

```
(enum)int? -> succeeds
(int?)enum -> the reverse fails

(int)enum? -> succeeds
(enum?)int -> the reverse fails
```

**Or in even simpler terms,**

> cast to non-nullable -> succeeds
>   cast to nullable -> fails

**Now I do know that once you box a value type, it can be cast back only to the original type. But since by C# rules, a boxed `int` can be cast to `enum` and a boxed `enum` can be cast to `int`, and a boxed `int` to `int?` and a boxed `int?` to `int`**, I was looking for a consistent understanding of other scenarios as well, ie the ones listed above. But I dont get the logic. **For one,** I feel if they all failed or if they all succeeded, it made more sense to developers. **Two,** even the successful casts look a little odd. I mean since a value type can be implicitly cast to its nullable equivalent (and not the other way around), a cast to nullable should anyway succeed, but with the current implementation a nullable type is being successfully cast to non-nullable which can even fail if the former had a null value. Had this whole thing been other way around, it would have been easier comprehending. An example like:

```
Sex? e = null;
object o = e;
int i = (int)o; //succeeds, but sure to explode on cast

//but

int i = 1;
object o = i;
Sex? e = (Sex?)o; //invalid cast, even though its always a safe cast
```

Questions:

1. So what C# rule is letting this happen?
2. Is there a simple way I can remember this?

Comment: Good question. I think it's actually a difference at the CLR level rather than the C# level. There are various things which *are* valid at the CLR level, but aren't allowed at the C# level - like casting between `int[]` and `uint[]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is a subtlety of the `unbox` and `unbox.any` IL instructions.

From ECMA 335, section III.4.32 (`unbox` operation - `unbox.any` is similar)

> Exceptions:
>   `System.InvalidCastException` is thrown if *obj* is not a boxed value type, *valuetype* is a *`Nullable<T>`* and *obj* is not a boxed *`T`*, or if the type of the value contained in *obj* is not *verifier-assignable-to* (III.1.8.2.3) *valuetype*.

So for example, in this case:

```
Sex e = Sex.Male;
object o = e;
int? i = (int?)o;
```

it fails *entirely correctly* - because *valuetype* is `Nullable<int>` and the value of *obj* is *not* a boxed `int`. The "verifier-assignable-to" part doesn't apply for the `Nullable<T>` case.

I doubt that any of this behaviour is described in the C# specification, unfortunately - I don't think the unboxing behaviour from "boxed `int`" to "enum with an underlying type of `int`" is described, as far as I can see, which is a sort of prerequisite to then including nullability in the mix.

Comment: Spec ninja strikes! :) Sorry for being late to respond. Indeed good find. Though I'm not entirely sure why it has been designed so, quite confusing.